# Transition between N background images with Y spacing between

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic website. I want the background image of the site to go through a transition of at least three GIFs:

1. Play the full length of the 1st GIF, twice
2. Play 2nd GIF for one length of time
3. Play 3rd GIF for e.g. 100 rounds of time
4. Play the 2nd GIF for one length of time
5. Loop over from start

Between each change, I would like the GIF to transition in a fading manner.
Ideally, I would like the first image to be loaded first; then the second image; then the third image, in order to make the transition smooth

How would I be able to achieve this?

I have found solutions that allow you to transition between two images, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it with a variable time between three different images, and downloading them sequentially

Comment: Could you add a basic example of the relevant HTML/CSS, preferably with the GIFs - it makes it much easier to give a considered answer. One question - do you know the length of time each of the individual GIFs takes to complete one cycle? And are they all just one cycle long?

Comment: Hey @AHaworth - they are each the same length of time!
As far as examples go, there's not a whole lot to showcase:
style.css:

html, body {
    [. . .]
    background: url("../wallpaper/wallpaper.gif") no-repeat center center fixed;
}

This is what I have curently. It has the three GIFs mashed into one.

However, the reason I would like to split it up into its constituent parts is to reduce load-times

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't clear enough, please make your code into a runnable snippet (including gifs we can actually see). This should help with doing that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example One immediate comment though, some versions of Safari IOS don't play nicely with attacment fixed so you may find yourself using a pseudo element, no big deal of course.